# WPF High Frequency Events and Updating the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application that is connected to a USB device. Said device raises an event at a rate of about 10/second. The data from these events updates a bar chart and a line chart. The bar chart represents the data from each event as they occur. The line chart is used to show values over time and is read from a collection of historical values from the start of the measurement.

My issue is, after about 3-5 minutes of measurements, the UI becomes very slow and eventually unresponsive. I think it is due to the below code snippet occurring too often and eventually locking up the UI thread.

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{ 
    Update the collection here.
}));
```

Is there a better way to update the collection so as to not lock up the UI?

Comment: If the code is working fine for a short time and then locks up after awhile... Your issue is you most likely have a memory leak as the lag doesn't start until the app has been running for a bit. If you look at task manager, the memory is probably increasing over time until it gets near max and your start to experience lag and freezing. Make sure the collection updates you are doing are getting disposed and are NOT stored on a variable that's not doing anything.

Comment: Memory doesn't seem to be an issue (only reaching about 90mb). And GC looks like it is pretty busy. What do you mean by "stored on a variable that's not doing anything".

Answer (score -1):

Surely you have already solved your problem. However, it is not a memory leak.
Most likely BeginInvokes enqueues more "update collection"-tasks than can be worked off by the Dispatcher. At some point the Dispatcher has to process thousands of tasks and at the same time BeginInvoke enqueues 10 new tasks every second.
To solve the problem, you need to make sure that the Dispatcher is not overwhelmed with new tasks. You could update the UI from a separate thread with the latest data only.

Comment: *"You could update the UI from a separate thread"* Most of your answer is correct, but this statement implies that the UI has no thread affinity and can be updated directly by any thread, which is wrong. Only one thread, the UI thread, can update the UI.